# What is the difference between prefix and postfix operators?

Tags: c, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

The following code prints a value of 9. Why? Here `return(i++)` will return a value of 11 and due to `--i` the value should be 10 itself, can anyone explain how this works?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i= fun(10);
    printf("%d\n",--i);
}

int fun (int i)
{
    return(i++);
}
```

Comment: `return i++` will return 10.  `return ++i` would return 11.

Comment: Because what is really happening are two things, first `i` is being returned and then `i` is being incremented. If you write `++i` then those two things happen in the opposite order.

Comment: By returning `i++` an expression is created `int i = i++;`. Let's rewrite this as `int j = i++;` so it's easier to explain. This is the post-fix version of `i`, which means increment `i` after setting `j = i`. Because, these are primitive integers, `i` is deep copied to `j` (it's not a shallow copy, with a pointer reference), and therefore `j = 10`. Then `i` is incremented, so `i = i + 1`, and therefore `i = 11`. The pre-fix version, will increment `i` before it's copied to `j`, and therefore both variables will have the same value (`j = 11`, `i = 11`).

Comment: @tfmontague That explanation really deserves to be in an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Just adding a comment here, for people like myself. They also have another difference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-59/ , check it for the difference in priorities.

Answer (score 99):

There is a *big* difference between postfix and prefix versions of `++`.

In the prefix version (i.e., `++i`), the value of `i` is incremented, and the value of the expression is the **new** value of `i`.

In the postfix version (i.e., `i++`), the value of `i` is incremented, but the value of the expression is the **original** value of `i`.

Let's analyze the following code line by line:

```
int i = 10;   // (1)
int j = ++i;  // (2)
int k = i++;  // (3)
```

1. `i` is set to `10` (easy).
2. Two things on this line:

   - `i` is incremented to `11`.
   - The **new** value of `i` is copied into `j`. So `j` now equals `11`.
3. Two things on this line as well:

   - `i` is incremented to `12`.
   - The **original** value of `i` (which is `11`) is copied into `k`. So `k` now equals `11`.

So after running the code, `i` will be 12 but both `j` and `k` will be 11.

The same stuff holds for postfix and prefix versions of `--`.

Comment: @RenéG Except that `i` was already incremented to `11` on the previous line.

Comment: I find it remarkable that people are still trying to edit this answer assuming I got the numbers wrong. All one has to do is run this code and print the values to see that I am correct.

Comment: The numbers are correct, but the code isn't explained very well. For a pre-fix expression `int j = ++i;`,  the variable `i` is incremented by one (`i = i + 1`, so `i = 11`), and then it's deep copied to `j` (so `j = 11`). And then for the post-fix expression `int k = i++;`, the variable `i` (which is still `11`), is first deep copied to `k` (so `k = 11`), and then `i` is incremented by one (so `i = 12`).

Comment: @tfmontague Let me know if you think this is better.

Comment: I would also add to this that the value categories of expressions differ. `i++` is a prvalue expression and `++i` is an lvalue expression.

Comment: (very late response) @wally As this is a C question there are no prvalues :)

Comment: Good point! It is not a prvalue (C++ only), but rather a non-lvalue object expression (rvalue). Years ago this answer was useful to me. A mention of the different value categories (correctly labeled for C of course) might help future readers.

Comment: For better understanding, I would switch the bullet points of 3). I would phrase it that `k` gets the value of `i` and THEN `i` gets incremented.

Comment: @Raildex I've heard it explained that way now and then, but it also leads to confusion. The fact is, `++` doesn't interact with `=` in any special way. So while the effect would be equivalent this particular case, it is literally backwards in terms of order of operations.

Answer (score 18):

**Prefix:**

```
int a=0;

int b=++a;          // b=1,a=1
```

before assignment the value of will be incremented.

**Postfix:**

```
int a=0;
int b=a++;  // a=1,b=0
```

first assign the value of 'a' to 'b' then increment the value of 'a'

Answer (score 11):

The function returns before `i` is incremented because you are using a post-fix operator (++). At any rate, the increment of `i` is not global - only to respective function. If you had used a pre-fix operator, it would be `11` and then decremented to `10`.

So you then return `i` as 10 and decrement it in the printf function, which shows `9` not `10` as you think.

Answer (score 7):

In fact `return (i++)` will only return 10.

The ++ and -- operators can be placed before or after the variable, with different effects. If they are before, then they will be processed and returned and essentially treated just like (i-1) or (i+1), but if you place the ++ or -- after the i, then the return is essentailly

```
return i;
i + 1;
```

So it will return 10 and never increment it.

Answer (score 5):

There are two examples illustrates difference

```
int a , b , c = 0 ; 
a = ++c ; 
b = c++ ;
printf (" %d %d %d " , a , b , c++);
```

- Here c has value 0 c increment by 1 then assign value 1 to a so value
  of `a = 1` and value of `c = 1`
- next statement assiagn value of `c = 1` to b then increment c by 1  so
  value of `b = 1` and value of `c = 2`
- in `printf` statement we have `c++` this mean that orginal value of c
  which is 2 will printed then increment c by 1 so `printf` statement
  will print `1 1 2` and value of c now is 3

you can use http://pythontutor.com/c.html

```
int a , b , c = 0 ; 
a = ++c ; 
b = c++ ;
printf (" %d %d %d " , a , b , ++c);
```

- Here in `printf` statement `++c` will increment value of c by 1 first then
  assign new value 3 to c so `printf` statement will print `1 1 3`

Answer (score 4):

The postfix increment `++` does not increase the value of its operand until after it has been evaluated. The value of `i++` is `i`.

The prefix decrement increases the value of its operand *before* it has been evaluated. The value of `--i` is `i - 1`.

Prefix increment/decrement change the value before the expression is evaluated. Postfix increment/decrement change the value after.

So, in your case, `fun(10)` returns 10, and printing `--i` prints `i - 1`, which is 9.

Answer (score 3):

i++ is post increment. The increment takes place after the value is returned.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that the function parameter named `i` and the variable named `i` in `main()` are two different variables. I think that doesn't matter that much to the present discussion, but it's important to know.

Second, you use the postincrement operator in `fun()`. That means the result of the expression is the value *before* `i` is incremented; the final value 11 of `i` is simply discarded, and the function returns 10. The variable `i` back in main, being a different variable, is assigned the value 10, which you then decrement to get 9.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation:**

**Step 1:** `int fun(int);` Here we declare the prototype of the function `fun()`.

**Step 2:** `int i = fun(10);` The variable i is declared as an integer type and the result of the `fun(10)` will be stored in the variable `i`.

**Step 3:** `int fun(int i){ return (i++); }` Inside the `fun()` we are returning a value `return(i++)`. It returns `10`. because `i++` is the post-increement operator.

**Step 4:** Then the control back to the main function and the value `10` is assigned to variable `i`.

**Step 5:** `printf("%d\n", --i);` Here `--i` denoted pre-increement. Hence it prints the value `9`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's keep this as simple as possible.

```
let i = 1
console.log('A', i)    // 1
console.log('B', ++i)  // 2
console.log('C', i++)  // 2
console.log('D', i)    // 3
```

A) Prints the value of I.

B) First i is incremented then the console.log is run with i as it's the new value.

C) Console.log is run with i at its current value, then i will get incremented.

D) Prints the value of i.

In short, if you use the pre-shorthand i.e(++i) I will get updated before the line is executed. If you use the post-shorthand i.e(i++) the current line will run as if I had not been updated yet then i get increased so the next time your interpreter comes across i it will have been increased.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the way the post-increment operator works. It returns the value of i and then increments the value.

Answer (score 2):

Actually what happens is when you use postfix i.e. i++, the initial value of i is used for returning rather than the incremented one. After this the value of i is increased by 1. And this happens with any statement that uses i++, i.e. first initial value of i is used in the expression and then it is incremented.

And the exact opposite happens in prefix. If you would have returned ++i, then the incremented value i.e. 11 is returned, which is because adding 1 is performed first and then it is returned.

Answer (score 1):

fun(10) returns 10. If you want it to return 11 then you need to use ++i as opposed to i++.

```
int fun(int i)
{
    return ++i;
}
```