# c = a+(b++); printf("output:c=%d\tb=%d\n",c,b); = 4,3

Tags: c

#### Code:

```
{
  int a =2,b=2,c=0;
  c = a+(b++);

  printf("output:c=%d\tb=%d\n",c,b);
}
```

#### Output:

```
output: c=4      b=3
```

How output of c = 4 here, My understanding is c=5, can any one explain it please?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators) is why.

Comment: assign to c the value of a plus b, then increment b.

Comment: Explain why *you* think it should be 5.

Comment: @Engine wait, are you telling me that new users' questions shouldn't be downvoted if they lack research effort (as this question clearly does)?

Comment: @engine the explanatory text of the closure already does that. downvoting does not exist for the purpose of welcoming new users. it exists for expressing towards the community that a qestion doesn't meet the site's quality standards.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is a difference between `++i` and `i++`!

Prefix/ Postfix

```
++i  // `Prefix` gets incremented `before` it get's used (e.g. in a operation)
i++  // `Postfix` gets incremented `after` it get's used (e.g. in a operation)
```

So that's why c is 4!

If you change `b++` to `++b` then c gets 5!

See also:

[What is the difference between prefix and postfix operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031326/3933332)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think b++ is *quite* doing what you think it is. `c = a+(b++)` says "c equals a plus b then increment b by one", therefore c will be 4. If you use `++b` instead, b will be incremented before the addition and c will be 5.

```
c = a+(b++); // c = 4
c = a+(++b); // c = 5
```

After each of these lines b will be 3, the only thing that changes between them is *when* b becomes 3.