# I don't understand the output ! a = (++c) - (b++)

Tags: java

This is an example practice. I try to figure out, but I always get the wrong answers. Assume that the user enters 1 3 5 at the first prompt and 1.5 2.0 2.5 at the second prompt.

```
// Problem6
import.java import java.util.Scanner;
  class problem2{
   public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b, c;
    double x, y, z;
    System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
    a = sc.nextInt();
    b = sc.nextInt();
    c = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter three doubles: ");       
    x = sc.nextDouble(); 
    y = sc.nextDouble();
    z = sc.nextDouble();
    a = (++c)-(b++);
    x += (z-y);
    b *= b;
    y = c*z;
    c = (int)(b-x);
    System.out.println("a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", c=" + c);
    System.out.println("x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", z=" + z);
    System.out.println("c/a=" + c/a);
    System.out.println("c%a=" + c%a);
   }
  }
```

Output :

- a=3, b=16, c=14
- x=2.0, y=15.0, z=2.5
- c/a =4
- c%a = 2

  please help! I really need to
  Specifically I don't understand how a = 3 and b = 16.
  I don't understand the a = (++c) - (b++)

Comment: In `a = (++c) - (b++)` c is incremented before the subtraction and b after, so it becomes a = 6 - 3.

Comment: Ah okay, 
How do I get b then? since it's b = b*b; assuming that b = 3, it does not equal to 16?

Comment: `b` is incremented after the subtraction, so it gets value of 4. And then 4*4=16.

Comment: "This is an example practice" - in that case, extend it a little bit and practice some debugging techniques while you're at it (like, moving step-by-step and observing the value of each variable at every step).

Comment: b has been incremented , so it is 4 * 4 = 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post Increment(n++) : First execute the statement then increase the value by one.

Pre Increment (++n) : First increase the value by one then execute the statement.

for example

int a = 8,i;

i= ++a + ++a + a++; // Ans: i = 9 + 10 + 10 = 20 then a = 8

all the Pre Increment will be done and then mathematical expression will be executed and at last Post Increment will be done.

a = (++c)-(b++);

so here also first "c" will be incremented then "b" will be subtracted and result will be saved in "a" and then "b" will be incremented.

Answer (score 6):

This

```
 a = (++c)-(b++);
```

is basically the same as

```
 c = c + 1; // pre-increment.
 a = c - b;
 b = b + 1; // post increment.
```

Comment: shouldn't it be b = b + 1;

Answer (score 2):

`a = (++c)-(b++);` means `a` equals `increased c` (which is 6) minus `b (increase after this line)` which is 3 in this line, but will be 4 in next. So `a = 6-3 = 3` and `b = 4 * 4 = 16`.

Comment: This made more sense to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = (++c) - (b++)
```

means `a = (c=c+1)-b; b = b+1;`

Prefix (++) means that we want change the variable first and then use it, postfix means that first we add b , and then change it's value . [What is the difference between prefix and postfix operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators)

Comment: BTW if you wrote `a = (++c) - (c++);` then `a` would be 0.

Comment: c will never get incremented again so pl remove last line c = c + 1

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela your edit was incorrect, because c+1 doesn't change the value of c , that's why I first added the line c = c+1. Now I think the explanation is more correct

Answer (score 1):

For expression `a = (++c) - (b++)`:
First, `c` is incremented by 1 and then used in an expression while `b` is used in an expression and then incremented. So `a` is evaluated as `6-3=3`.

Answer (score 1):

The unary operator ++ can be put before or after a variable.

Putting it before means "increment by 1 BEFORE you evaluate this expression" and putting it after means "increment by 1 AFTER you evaluate this expression".

So if I said (psuedo code):

```
a = 5
print ++a
```

That would produce:

```
6
```

Because the incrementation happens before it's passed to print. However, if I did this:

```
a = 5
print a++
print a
```

The output would be:

```
5
6
```

As the incrementation happens after it's passed to print.

So ++c evaluates to 5+1=6 and b++ just evaluates to 3 (the initial value of b). Meaning (++c) - (b++) evaluates to 3.

Answer (score 0):

a = (++c) - (b++)

++c is a preincrement, which means you add 1 to it before doing the calculation
b++ is a postincrement, so you add 1 to it after doing the calculation

So the formula means:

a equals (c plus 1) minus b. Then add 1 to b.

Answer (score 0):

As per your input, `a = 1, b = 3, c=5`

`a = (++c)-(b++)` is evaluated as:

1. ++c, set `c` as `5 + 1` and return value as `6`
2. b++, return value `3` and now set `b` as `3 + 1`
3. set `a` as `6` - `3` gives `3`

b *= b, here is already `4` so `4 * 4` is `16`