# New to C - I am struggling to figure this out

Tags: c

I don't understand how the results of this is :

```
2
2
2
```

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a = 1, b = 1, x = 0, y = 0;
double w;
x = 1 + a++;
printf("x = %d\n", x);
printf("a = %d\n", a);
y = ++b;
printf("y = %d\n", y);
printf("b = %d\n", b);
}
```

Ok i understood the postfix and prefix but i still don't understand why a and b are 2 and not 1 .
They are not being saved anywhere 
so when you say x=1+a++ and y=++b,
b becomes 2 and is saved in y . How does b keeps being 2 when not saved anywhere such as b=++b .

Sorry i am not sure if you guys follow what i am thinking.

Comment: Maybe you should try writing some C#?

Comment: I am but i also have to study certain pdfs for school and i struggle understanding this.

Comment: You need to clarify whether you are asking about C# or C. Those are two different languages.

Comment: @eternity123 What he means is that you have written that you are struggling in `C#` yet you are writing code in `C`.

Comment: I truly apologise i meant C , i though it's the same thing .Sorry once again.

Comment: `a++` *doesn't* mean `a+1`. It is an expression resulting in the old value of `a`, and increments `a` as a side-effect.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators

Comment: @eternity123: If you are going to include program output in your question can you post the __actual__ output. What you have now obviously doesn't match the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand how the increment operator works.

You have two operations :

- X++ => Return the value of X, then increment it by 1.
- ++X => Increment X by 1 then return it.

In your situation, the line with a problem is here : `x = 1 + a++;`

This translates into :

- Return the value of a (1) and increment it (a becomes 2).
- Set the value of x equal to the 1 + the value returned by a (1) (x becomes 2)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok i understood the postfix and prefix but i still don't understand why a and b are 2 and not 1 . They are not being saved anywhere so when you say x=1+a++ and y=++b, b becomes 2 and is saved in y . How does b keeps being 2 when not saved anywhere such as b=++b .

Sorry i am not sure if you guys follow what i am thinking.

Comment: @eternity123 Using ++b is equivalent of saying `b = b + 1`. In other words, doing ++ DOES save in that variable.

Comment: Oh that clears a lot thanks .Thanks for everyone who answered my questions in god speed. I really like this website. Take care everyone.

Comment: @eternity123 No problem, feel free to set my answer as official if this has helped you.

Comment: i would but i have no clue how haha

Comment: @eternity123 Click on the check-mark to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**C Language Pre-increment and Post-increment Operators**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1, x = 0, y = 0;
    double w;
    x = 1 + a++;
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    y = ++b;
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
    printf("b = %d\n", b);
}
```

Pre-increment means *increment variable **before** its value is used*. Post-increment means *increment variable **after** its value has been used*. To understand how these operators work, let's look at the first case:

```
a = 1;
x = 1 + a++; // ++ on right means post-increment
```

First you're setting the value of `a` to `1`. Then you're saying add `a` (*value is `1`*) to `x` (*value is `1`*). The result is `x` has a value of `2`.  And then, *after* the statement is done executing, as a side-effect, `a` is incremented, because you used the post-increment form of *`++`*. So after `x` has been set to a value of `2`, the value of `a` will become `2`.

Instead, if you used a a pre-increment operator:

```
a = 1;
x = 1 + (++a); // ++ on left means pre-increment
```

Again, you start with `a = 1`, but this time, `a` is incremented *before* its value is used in the statement, because `++` on the left-side means pre-increment. In other words, first, `a` is incremented to the value of `2`. Then `a` is added to `x` (whose value is `1`), setting the value of `x` to `3`.

In both the above cases, `a` starts out with a value of `1` and becomes `2`. The difference is whether that happens before or after the value of `a` is used in the expression.

Comment: The side-effect could occur any time during the execution of the statement, in both cases. There is no before/after ordering between the evaluation and the side-effect.