# C: Why does this code print this?

Tags: c, while-loop, char

can somebody explain why does this code print 5 A's `AAAAA` and not 4 A's `AAAA`

value of char `'A' - 65`, `'B' - 66` and `'Z' - 90`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a = 'B', b = 'A';
    while (a++ < 'Z') {
        if (a % 5 == 0)
            printf("%c", b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I calculated multiple times and I got 4 A's as a result, so I do not understand why correct answer is 5 A's

Comment: Are you counting the case where `a` is 89 for the `while` test and 90 for the `if` test?

Comment: Which values of `a` do you believe result in an A being output? Can you modify your code to test your belief?

Comment: The probable misunderstanding here is the behavior of `a++`.  It is compared with 'Z' *before* it is incremented, but then it's used on the next line after the increment operation, as @aschepler indicated.  Try it with `++a` instead and notice what happens.

Comment: You could improve your understanding of what's going on by printing: `printf("%d %c %c\n", a, a, b);` instead of what you have.  This would allow you to see the values driving the decision in the body of the loop.  It would be better if you printed a newline at the end of the output even without the debugging print.

Comment: It will be clear and easy if you change your printf to `printf("%d, ",a);`

Comment: when a is 89, 89%5 is not 0 so 90<90 is not possible? 

or is it like this: 
first while tests 89<90 then it increments a to 90 inside while loop, 90 %5 is 0 and that's why 5 A's ?

Comment: When `a` is 89 in the `while`, it is `90` in the `if` (because the increment occurs after the value is read for the test but before anything in the `if` is executed).  So `a % 5` is `0` when `a` is `90` in the `if`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you Jonathan and everyone else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's iterate through your code "manually".

```
Stop condition: a < 90 ('Z')

    a = 'B' = 66
    ...
    a = 70 => 'A' printed
    ...
    a = 75 => 'A' printed
    ...
    a = 80 => 'A' printed
    ...
    a = 85 => 'A' printed
    ...
    a = 89 =>
```

- condition is checked (a++ < 90) and evaluates to true and since you use an postfix increment operator (a++), variable a gets incremented after the comparison and therefore, inside the next operation "if(a%5==0)", variable a has now the value of 90, thus passing the check and getting your 5th 'A' printed

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators