# Why is a multiplication without an LHS valid in C?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, lalr

Why is this piece of C code valid?

```
int main() {
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    x * y; // See this?!
}
```

The most ubiquitous examples that explain the need for back-tracking in parser often shows this. And then goes on to say that depending on what `x` is, the meaning of `*` will change. For some time, I believed it was just a way of explaining until I compiled it and found to my surprise, it compiles and works!

Why is a multiplication without an LHS valid in C and what is it used for?

**Edit**
This confusion is because, the same piece of code won't compile in Java. It seems Java compiler tries to prevent operations without LHS.

[image]

Comment: Not all valid code is useful.

Comment: No one would spend years doing something useless. No?

Comment: Allowing it makes the grammar simpler. Also, it's useful in expression statements (a gcc/clang/tcc extension).

Comment: Did you spend years writing this? Do you know anyone who has?

Comment: Considering that assignment is an expression returning a value, requiring that every expression's value be used would be *difficult*.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41942049/2615940

Comment: @user2357112: Expressions causing name lookup and then change the meaning of `*` isn't something you think off hand and put it in to your compiler for fun. Reckon, it ought to have some purpose. Hence the question.

Comment: The useful and useless ways to use `*` weren't implemented separately. No one made any special effort to put in useless uses of it. The useless uses exist because it was simpler to have them than to not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - What does x+1 means without assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942049/c-what-does-x1-means-without-assignment)

Comment: The value of that expression is used to be assigned to an lvalue. It is valid because it has to be, otherwise it couldn't be assigned to anything.

Comment: @JulienLopez I wanted an explanation from grammar point-of-view and a need to even have such a statement as valid. Not what it means, like in the possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is referred to as an **expression statement**.

From section 6.8.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *1*
>   expression-statement:
>
> expression<sub>opt</sub> ;
>
> *2* The  expression  in  an  expression  statement  is  evaluated  as  a  void  expression  for  its  side effects.

In your case, the expression is a multiplication.  This statement has no side effect, so it has no effect at all.

If on the other hand you had this:

```
i++;
```

That's an expression that does have a side effect.

This is also considered an expression:

```
a = b * c;
```

In this case, the side effect is the assignment operator.

Comment: What side-effects? How do you trap those side-effects?

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer See my edit.  The increment, decrement, and assignment operators are elements of an expression that have a side effect.

Comment: Like `printf("Hello ") + printf("World!\n");`. Will have very visible side effect.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Isn't that undefined due to unsequenced side-effects?

Comment: @EOF oh.. didn't think about that... Then `5 + printf("Hello world!\n");` :)

Comment: @EOF: They're [indeterminately sequenced](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p10); it's guaranteed that one is sequenced after the other, but not guaranteed which goes first.

Comment: @dbush This answer makes sense with `Dietrich Epp`'s explanation. But I can't seem to tick both. Could you please adjust this answer with his?

Answer (score 4):

It's not used for anything.

The reason that it's valid is because it makes the language simpler.  An expression is a valid statement all by itself, so you can do things like this:

```
f(x, y);
```

Even if the definition of `f` is:

```
int f(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
}
```

There's no point to that either, but figuring out exactly which expressions "make sense" would make the language more complicated.  It's good enough that the compiler warns us:

```
$ cc -c -Wall -Wextra test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3:7: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     x * y;
     ~~^~~
```

Comment: Maybe a better example would be `printf` which returns an `int` or `std::cout` which returns a `std::ostream &`. It would be a huge pain to have to assign every return value.

Comment: C++ with operator overloading makes things a bit different.

Comment: It makes sense when you read answers from `DietrichEpp` and `dbush`. But I can't seem to tick both.

Comment: @DietrichEpp could you please add/edit your answer from `dbush` so the explanation clearly flows from grammar? Thanks.