# C Quizz with 2 questions does not work?

Tags: c, boolean

I am currently learning C, and I have had this problem for some time. If it runs, it does not work how it should work, and sometimes it just does not run.
It is supposed to if you give a correct answer, you get a point, but even if you get it wrong, it still says its correct and gives you a point. Anyone could help me here?
Here is the code:

This works fine

```
char name[50], answer;
int point;
printf("Enter your name!\n");
scanf("%s", &name);
printf("\t \t \t Welcome to the game, %s! \n", name);
point = 0;
printf("\t \t \t POINTS: %d \n", point);
```

And here is the question and answer..does not work that well

```
printf("2+2? \n");
printf("a) 4 \n");
printf("b) 5 \n");
scanf("%s", &answer);
if (answer = "a") {
    printf("Correct\n");
    point++;
    printf("\t \t \t POINTS: %d \n", point);
}
else {
    printf("Not correct");
}
printf("2+3? \n");
printf("a) 5 \n");
printf("b) 4 \n");
scanf("%s", &answer);
if (answer = "a") {
    printf("Correct\n");
    point++;
    printf("\t \t \t POINTS: %d \n", point);
}
else {
    printf("Not correct");
}
```

Comment: Please define "does not work that well"

Comment: `scanf("%s", &answer);` if the answer is more than one character ( including nul ) you'll be writing into unallocated memory and the behaviour will be undefined.

Comment: @xing - Wrong - `strcmp` is what is required

Comment: Then `scanf("%s", &answer);` is wrong

Comment: @EdHeal It is, it will invoke UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read in `answer` with `%s`. However, it is a `char`. Therefore you should read in the answer using `scanf("%c", &answer);`.
Next thing: If you have an `if`-statement and you want to compare two values, you do that by using `==`. **Note** that `=` is an assignment operator and assigns a value to something, in your case it assigns `"a"` to `answer`and `==` checks for equality.
When comparing characters, e.g. `if (answer == "a")` don't use `" "`. Those indicate a `const char *` that is terminated with the `NULL` character (`\0`). Instead, to check for single characters, use `' '`, e.g. `if (answer == 'a'`.
**EDIT**:
Instead of using

```
point++;
printf("\t \t \t POINTS: %d \n", point);
```

you can do that in one line:

```
printf("\t \t \t POINTS: %d \n", ++point);
```

You used postfix-notation `point++`. That increments the variable **after** the command. Using `++point` increments the variable in the very same command. For more check out this question about postfix/prefix, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators).