# When does the code inside if statement get executed?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following 3 scenarios.

```
var y = 1;
if (function f(){}) {
   y += typeof f;
}
console.log(y);     // "1undefined"
```

the above output indicates that `function f(){}` is just checked for its truthiness, but is not defined before the execution of `if block`.

```
var y = 1;
if (y--) {
   y += typeof f;
}
console.log(y);     // "0undefined"
```

However, here we get the value of y as 0, that means the expression inside `if condition` is executed before the `if block`. But shouldn't the `if block` be skipped as `y--` evaluates to 0 which is a falsey value as in below.

```
var y = 1;
if (0) {
   y += typeof f;
}
console.log(y);     // "1"
```

Comment: No, `y--` evaluates to `1`, not `0`.  When `--` is *after* the variable, the overall value is what it was *before* the decrement.

Comment: Try `y = 1; console.log(y--); console.log(y);`

Comment: I'm not really sure what your asking here.

Comment: Even though it's C, you should read [What is the difference between prefix and postfix operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031326/691711)

Comment: only in the first case, something is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the above output indicates that function f(){} is just checked for its truthiness, but is not defined

A named function expression creates a variable which shares its name (`f` in this case) only inside its own scope.

You *never* create a variable `f` which is in a scope accessible to your `y += typeof f;` statement.

---

> But shouldn't the if block be skipped as y-- evaluates to 0

`y--` doesn't evaluate to 0.

It evaluates to `1` and **then** decrements `y` to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (function f(){})
```

This doesn't define `f` because it's just a *named function **expression***. Expressions don't declare a function in the local scope under the name `f`, so no `f` is being created.

```
if (y--)
```

The *post-decrement* operator first returns the value of `y` and *then* decrements it. Compare with the *pre-decrement* operator `--y`.

Those are the reasons you get the behaviour you get. When "if is executed" is irrelevant.