# Recursion order of outputs in C

Tags: c, recursion

I have this recursive function in C,and i'm trying to understand why it's printing the way it does:

```
void rec(int x, int y){
 if (x == y) 
     return;
 rec(x--, y+1);
 printf("%3d%6.2f\n", x, (float) y);
}
```

I know that ther output for rec(8,4) is:

```
7 7.00
7 6.00
7 5.00
7 4.00
```

why the `X` value stays 7?as i understand it, the `x--` should happen only after the line it's written.If not,why the value stays 7 and not decreasing?
Also why the `y` value is decreasing?because it starts printing when the recursion is stopped?

I'm pretty new to C,and not used to all the little details that require attention(i'm coming from java)

thanks for any help!

Comment: For the `y` part, it's because you print *after* the recursive call, so the results will be printed in reverse order (last call first, first call last)

Comment: Each recursive call creates its own `x` with no relation to any other (older) `x`

Comment: thanks @FedericoklezCulloca that's what i thought

Comment: @pmg what do you mean exactly?

Comment: It's like nested scopes: `{ int x = 10; { int x = -1; { int x = 42; /* x here is 42 */ } /* x here is -1 */ } /* x here is 10 */ }`

Comment: please note that if you fix your code to be `rec(--x, ++y)` your code might never terminate because of for example: `rec(3,2) --> rec(2,3) --> rec(1,4) --> ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue of syntax but rather recursion and the call stack.

First off: doing `rec(x--, y+1)` passes the original value of x to the function and after the function is done, x is modified(but the modification is never saved). The same would happen to y if you passed it like this: `rec(x--, y++)`. The "correct" way of doing it is changing the value before evaluating the function, as you did with y previously or like this: `rec(--x, ++y)`.

Once you do this you will see that y is **de**creasing and x is **in**creasing. Why?
Because of the call stack. The function that is called last is will be done first. For *this purpose* you can imagine a calling a function as just copy pasting the code with the parameters already set. It would then look something like this:

```
void rec(int x, int y){
 if !(x == y) 
     rec(--x, ++y);

 printf("%3d%6.2f\n", x, (float) y);
}

...

if !(4 == 0){ 
     if !(3 == 1) 
          if !(2 == 2) 
              rec(--x, ++y);} // we are done now, no more "code is inserted"

          printf("%3d%6.2f\n", 2, (float) 2);

     printf("%3d%6.2f\n", 3, (float) 1);

printf("%3d%6.2f\n", 4, (float) 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

For the `y` part, it's because you print *after* the recursive call, so the results will be printed in reverse order (last call first, first call last).

For the `x` part it's exactly because you're using post-decrement. When `rec` gets called it's passed the value it was passed before, and *then* it gets decremented. So you're always passing `8` to the recursive call, which then gets decremented and when the recursion ends it will finally print `7`.

Answer (score 4):

When using the postfix decrement operator `x--`, [the value of the expression is the value of the variable before the decrement is applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031409/1506086). That means that the value of x is only actually decremented in each call of `rec` after all of the child recursive calls are already done. That's why you see `7` printed at each step - each function does execute the decrement and prints it, but passes `8` to the child function.

However, if you were to prefix decrement operator `--x`, the value would be the value of the variable **after** the assignment was applied. This would give you the result you want, where the variable decrements with each recursive call. You could also do what you did for the y variable, and specify `x - 1` rather than `x--`.

Answer (score 3):

**X**: this is because you are using *post*-decrement in the `rec` call. What it does is first passing the current value of X to the call, then decrementing X:

```
rec(x--, y+1);
```

is equivalent to:

```
rec(x, y+1); x-=1;
```

**Y**: you print after the recursive call, so the first to print will be the "last" call made to `rec`, hence the one with the highest y value.