# C++17 post increment operation

Tags: c++, c++17

C++17

Could someone explain how

```
int number{5};
number = (number++) + 10;
```

Gives an output of 15 while

```
int number {5};
number = (++number) + 10;
```

Gives an output of 16?

Comment: Why do you want to write code like this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 - Maybe he does't want to write code like this, maybe he just wants to learn how to read code like this when he encounters it.

Comment: @selbie Maybe! Good thing I answered the question ;)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot This is about more than just the difference between prefix and postfix. Sort of.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 my bad. I'll vote reopen then.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I'm ambivalent tbh. On the one hand we don't really need yet another of these questions. On the other, meh

Comment: Thankyou for your answers,sorry I could'nt respond sooner

Answer (score 9):

Before [P0145](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) was adopted (in C++17), the first example had undefined behaviour. Anything could happen.

Before C++11, both had undefined behaviour.

In C++17, [neither has undefined behaviour](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf). That doesn't mean it's code you want to be writing.

The explanation of your output is simple, if we understand [the difference between postfix and prefix increment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031409/560648):

#### Case 1

- `number++`: `number` becomes 6 but the expression evaluates to 5
- ten is added to the expression
- the result (15) is stored in `number`

#### Case 2

- `++number`: `number` becomes 6 and the expression evaluates to 6
- ten is added to the expression
- the result (16) is stored in `number`

Comment: The pre-increment version has been well-defined since C++11, since the side-effect of the increment is sequenced-before its value computation which is sequenced-before the assignment's side-effect.

Comment: @walnut Fair, I was considering the whole question as one program

Answer (score 0):

Pre increment increments the value and returns the incremented result. Post increment returns the value before the increment, then increments the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unary post-increment is executed after the statement executed. so, the number is added first and then number is 15.
But in pre-increment case the unary operator excited first then the current statement is resolved and result is calculated to 16.

More information:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

```
int number{ 5 }; 
01013C88 mov dword ptr [number],5 
number = (number++) + 10; 
01013C8F mov eax,dword ptr [number] 
01013C92 add eax,0Ah 
01013C95 mov dword ptr [number],eax 
01013C98 mov ecx,dword ptr [number] 
01013C9B add ecx,1 
01013C9E mov dword ptr [number],ecx
```

Assmebly code show the two time addition

Comment: this has nothing to do with when "the statement executed". The link you should be giving is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: int number{ 5 };
   01013C88  mov         dword ptr [number],5  
   number = (number++) + 10;
01013C8F  mov         eax,dword ptr [number]  
01013C92  add         eax,0Ah  
01013C95  mov         dword ptr [number],eax  
01013C98  mov         ecx,dword ptr [number]  
01013C9B  add         ecx,1  
01013C9E  mov         dword ptr [number],ecx  

Assmebly code show the two time addition