# Kotlin (Java) - Incrementation symbol ++ prefix and suffix - what is the exact meaning?

Tags: java, kotlin, increment

I am pasting the code below. The questions are written as a,b,c,d and e next to the codes. I could not try this by myself because I don't have an installed Android Studio currently. Can you explain?

```
        var pos = -1
        var ch = 0
        if (++pos < str.length) {        //a) here what is the value of pos?
                ch = str[pos].toInt()    //b) and here what is the value of pos?
            } else ch = -1
```

Next sample:

```
        var pos = -1
        var ch = 0
        if (pos++ < str.length) {        //c) here what is the value of pos?
                ch = str[pos].toInt()    //d) and here what is the value of pos?
            } else ch = -1
                                         //e) and at last what is the value of pos?
```

Edit: Kotlin documentation is lacking for explaining the difference, I couldn't understand from there.

Comment: https://play.kotlinlang.org/

Comment: This post is about C, but it does a pretty good job explaining the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031326/2422776

Comment: The code is the same in both snippets. Only the comments differ. Is that intended? Did you see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html?

Comment: @IR42 thank you, I didn't know if such a website exists

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html - scroll down to the prefix/postfix bit. Here's the Kotlin explanation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#increments-and-decrements

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks, I already got it:)