# Why does the console prints yes statement?

Tags: c++

```
int a{1};

while(a--){

cout<<"yes";}
```

Why does the console prints "yes", the value of while should be 0

Comment: Learn about `a--` versus `--a`. Search for prefix / postfix. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators)

Comment: Because `a` has been initialized with `1` and `a--` uses post decrement operator.

Answer (score 1):

`a--` (it's called using a **postfix operator**) means first inspect the value of `a`, then decrement. I.e. the value of the expression `a--` is the value of `a` before decrement.

Therefore in the first `while` iteration it is still 1.

If you used `--a` instead (which is a called using a **prefix operator**), you would not have seen the "yes" printed,
because `--a` means first decrement, then inspect the resulting value.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `a` has been initialized with value `1`. Moreover, the expression `a--` uses **postfix-decrement** operator. So the expression `a--` has 2 effects:

1. decrements `a` so that the new value of `a` becomes `0`.
2. returns the old value of `a` which was `1`.

Thus the condition holds true and the while block is entered one time.

---

On the other hand, if you were to use `--a`, then the while block will not be executed because `--a` uses **prefix-decrement operator** which returns the decremented value(`0` in your case) instead of returning the old value. So the condition will not be satisfied and the while block is never entered.