# Return type of decltype()

Tags: c++, c++11

In the below code, why `decltype(++c)` returns `int&` instead of `int` whereas `decltype(a++)` return `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    int32_t a {};
    decltype(a++) b; // OK

    int32_t c{};
    decltype(++c) d; // error: 'd' declared as reference but not initialized

    std::cout << "typeid(b) = " << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "typeid(d) = " << typeid(d).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: because postfix increment returns a copy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between prefix and postfix operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators)

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik  I don't see return types mentioned, or even implied, in any of the answers there.

Comment: @Spencer then look at [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You see, I **did** actually link to that exact page in my answer. I was objecting to Sergey's proposing that SE page as a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the built-in pre-increment operator is an lvalue referring to the operand (which then holds the value after the increment). This means that, for example, `++a = 1;` is valid. The result of `++a` refers to the variable `a`, which can be assigned a value `1`.

The result of the built-in post-increment operator is a prvalue of the previous value of the operand (it couldn't be an lvalue referring to the operand since post-increment is supposed to give the *previous* value before the increment). This means that, eg `a++ = 1;` is not valid since the result of `a++` is not referring to `a`, but is just the original value of `a`, and a value can't be assigned a value.

`decltype` applied to a prvalue expression gives a non-reference. Applied to an lvalue expression, it gives an lvalue reference to the expression's type. This mimics the return types you would need to use to get the same value categories for the expressions if you overloaded the increment operators.

Comment: Note that everything said also applies to the pre-decrement and post-decrement operators, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of the pre- and postfix operators' descriptions in the Standard.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) has a little table that shows the signature of the two operators, where ut says:

> Prefix versions of the built-in operators return references and postfix versions return values...

*by definition*, the pre-increment operator returns a **reference**, as if it were declared:

```
T& T::operator++();
T& operator++(T& a);
```

the post-increment operator returns a **value**:

```
T T::operator++(int);
T operator++(T& a, int);
```

To avoid the error try

```
#include <type_traits>
//   
// ...later...
//
std::remove_reference_t<decltype(++c)> d;
```

Comment: *"by definition"* This is not how those operators are defined for built-in types. It's merely a suggestion of how to define them for your own classes. I don't think operators for built-in types even count as functions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Look at the fine print under the table: _"Prefix versions of the built-in operators return references and postfix versions return values, "_.

Comment: Yep, adding "*as if* it were declared" is more correct. I still think cppreference is being a bit sloppy by mentioning "references and values" instead of lvalues and prvalues.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Not all of us can be language lawyers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Anyway, probably the only reason to use `decltype(++c)` is in a template, where you have to account for someone's unconventional overload of that operator.