# Increments --i and i--

Tags: javascript, increment

Please can someone clearly explain to me in a very detailed layman understanding manner. The actually difference between --i and i-- And where exactly should which be used over which. Example or pictorial explanations is welcomed.
I have been into programming and I understand other complex stuffs like recursion, iteration, control structure etc but I haven't really got a full understanding of that increment operator. I just use any for any of my codes in my projects.
Please help.

Comment: Python has neither of those...

Comment: They're decrements not increments.

Comment: And there's plenty of results when you search for "difference between pre and post increment", such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between pre-increment and post-increment in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-loop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between prefix and postfix operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators)

Comment: @shadygray They behave the same way as decrements ++i and i++.:)

Comment: Which language?  Their behavior isn't exactly the same across C and JavaScript.

Comment: @shadygray By the way in C you can find also multiplications like **i.:)

Comment: Don't spam language tags. Only tag the language relevant to the question. Since the answers given are JS, I've removed the C and Python.  Feel free to adjust if incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let count;
count = 0;

console.log('count--',count--);

count = 0;

console.log('--count',--count);

// after either count-- or --count the value of count will be -1
// but the difference is the immediate value returned by the operation
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify you can read

- the "--" or "++" as 'decrement'/'increment'
- the variable name as 'use the value'

So with `--i` you decrement then use the value
But with `i--` you use the value then decrement

In real use cases it mean

```js
function print(value) {
    console.log(value)
}

let i = 10;
print(i--) //Use then decrease => use i as a 10 then after using it in the function i is decreased
//The function is called like print(10)
//From here, the value of i is 9

let j = 10;
print(--j) //Decrease then use => decrese j to 9 then call the function with the decreased value
//The function is called like print(9)
//From here, the value of j is 9

j = ++i //j is set to 10 and i is 10 too
i = j++ //i is still ten but j become 11
```

(And just to be clear, python do not have those operators, only the `+=` and `-=`)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Ikegami edited the language tags while I was writing this, so it may not be relevant anymore*</sup>

This is easier if you pick a single language.

With respect to C:

- The *result* of the expression `i--` is the current value of `i`; as a *side effect*, the value stored in `i` is decremented.  Given the code:

  ```
  int i = 2;
  int x = i--;
  ```

  the value stored in `x` will be 2 and the value stored in `i` will be 1.  It's logically equivalent to writing:

  ```
  tmp <- i
  x <- tmp
  i <- i - 1
  ```

  with the caveat that the updates to `x` and `i` can occur in any order, even simultaneously.

  The *result* of the expression `--i` is the current value of `i` minus 1; as a *side effect*, the value stored in `i` is decremented.  Given the code:

  ```
  int i = 2; 
  int x = --i;
  ```

  the value stored in `x` will be 1 and the value stored in `i` will be 1.  It's logically equivalent to writing:

  ```
  tmp <- i - 1
  x <- tmp
  i <- i - 1
  ```

  with the same caveat as above.

Note that the side effect does not have to be applied immediately upon evaluation; it only has to be applied before the next sequence point.  If you have an expression like `z = x-- * --y;`, the updates to `x` and `y` may not be applied until after `z` has been assigned:

```
tmp1 <- x
tmp2 <- y - 1
   z <- tmp1 * tmp2
   x <- x - 1
   y <- y - 1
```

or the updates may be applied immediately:

```
y <- y - 1
z <- x * y
x <- x - 1
```

or some other order.  For this reason among several others, expressions like `i-- * i--` are *undefined* - they're not guaranteed to yield a consistent result.

I can't speak to JavaScript - I know the results are the same (`i--` yields the current value of `i`, `--i` yields the current value of `i` minus 1) and they have the same side effects, but I don't know how the side effects are handled, whether they're applied immediately or not, whether expressions like `i-- * i--` are meaningful, etc.

AFAIK Python doesn't have autoincrement/decrement operators.