# C Code Algebraic output is not what I thought

Tags: c

Please explain to me how th3 output is `11`.

```
int main(){
    int delta = 12, alpha = 5, a = 0;
    a = delta - 6 + alpha++;
    printf("%d", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a = 12 - 6 + 5`? If it was `++alpha`, it would be 12.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between prefix and postfix operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators)

Answer (score 3):

In C, putting `++` after a variable in an expression increments it *after* the expression is evaluated. Therefore, substituting the variables for their values, it would be `a = 12 - 6 + 5`, and afterwards `alpha` would be equal to 6.

If you put `++` before the variable, it increments it before the expression is evaluated. So therefore, if you had done `a = delta - 6 + ++alpha`, it would have been 12.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `x++` is the *current* value of `x` - as a side effect, `x` is incremented.  *Logically*, your expression is equivalent to writing

```
tmp = alpha;
a = delta - 6 + tmp;
alpha = alpha + 1;
```

with the caveat that the assignment to `a` and the update to `alpha` can occur in any order, even simultaneously.  Point is that `a` is computed with the value of `alpha` before the increment.  Now, your specific compiler may choose to generate code like

```
a = delta - 6 + alpha;
alpha = alpha + 1;
```

because that makes sense here, but the point is that it isn't specified exactly when the side effect to `alpha` is applied.

The result of `++x` is the current value of `x` *plus one* - as a side effect, `x` is incremented.  Had you used `++alpha` in your statement, it would logically equivalent to writing

```
tmp = alpha + 1;
a = delta - 6 + tmp;
alpha = alpha + 1;
```

with the same caveat as above.  `a` is computed with the value of `alpha + 1`.  Again, your compiler may choose to generate code equivalent to

```
alpha = alpha + 1;
a = delta - 6 + alpha;
```

or it could have done something like

```
a = delta - 6 + (alpha + 1);
alpha = alpha + 1;
```

Again, it isn't specified exactly when the side effect is applied.