# Trying to understand recursion in JS... check my simple code

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to wrap my head around recursive functions. I've tried a number of entry level exercises with no success. For example, I put this code into JS fiddle. I intended for it to take the sum of all numbers from 1 to n.

```
function sumAll(n) {
  if (n == 1 ) {
    return 1;
  } else if (n > 1) {
    return sumAll(n--) + n;
  }
}

console.log(sumAll(3));
```

feeding 3 to the function should give me '6'. I get an error, though.

Comment: What do you think `n--` does?  How does that differ from `--n`, and why is it relevant?

Comment: That said, IMO using `n - 1` is much clearer--zero cognitive overhead and anyone reading the code will understand exactly what's happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators

Comment: Tangential: instead of reporting "I got an error" be specific and tell **us** what the error is--it saves everyone a small bit of thought.

Comment: doing some reading on 'n--' vs '--n' now, thanks. Also, noted about the specific error. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--` suffix operator will evaluate to the **original** value of `n`, and the subtraction from `n` will happen afterwards (which is also not desired as you still want to do `+ n`). That means the recursive call gets the *same* value for `n` as the caller, and so you don't get closer to the end...

Don't use `--` here, but `-1`:

```js
function sumAll(n) {
  if (n == 1 ) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (n > 1) {
    return sumAll(n-1) + n;
  }
}

console.log(sumAll(3));
```

Comment: you can also remove the else if statement to make things even easier to read

Comment: Sure, but maybe the author wanted to prevent infinite recursion when calling `sumAll(0)` or `sumAll(-1)` and have the function return `undefined` instead, which I actually think is a good idea. Even better would be to have a base case that catches all possible states where no recursion should happen, like `(!(n > 1))`. But all this distracts from the original question.

Comment: if ( n <=1 ) return n;

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will enjoy a repeatable technique that can guide you through designing your recursive function. Let's solve `sumAll` using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. If *n* is zero, return the empty sum, zero
2. (inductive) *n* is negative or positive. If *n* is negative, return the negative result of the subproblem *sumAll(-n)*
3. (inductive) *n* is positive. Return *n* plus the result of the subproblem *sumAll(n - 1)*

```js
function sumAll(n) {
  if (n == 0)                  // 1
    return 0
  else if (n < 0)              // 2
    return -sumAll(-n)
  else
    return n + sumAll(n - 1)   // 3
}

console.log(sumAll(-10), sumAll(0), sumAll(10))
// -55 0 55
```

Here is `sumAll` written using a `switch` instead. It behaves identically but maybe you will find the syntax nicer to read -

```js
function sumAll(n) {
  switch (true) {
    case n == 0:  return 0                  // 1
    case n < 0:   return -1 * sumAll(-n)    // 2 
    default:      return n + sumAll(n - 1)  // 3
  } 
}

console.log(sumAll(-10), sumAll(0), sumAll(10))
// -55 0 55
```

Here is `sumAll` again as a pure, functional expression -

```js
const sumAll = (n = 0) =>
  n == 0                // 1
    ? 0
: n < 0                 // 2
    ? -1 * sumAll(-n)
: n + sumAll(n - 1)     // 3


console.log(sumAll(-10), sumAll(0), sumAll(10))
// -55 0 55
```